# iMacro dynamic attribute data extract

Tags: imacros

I have been trying to resolve this issue through different angles but not having any luck. Even tried using PHP to generate iMacro code to do this but really no luck.

Basically I am trying to use iMacro to pull some form data but the problem is on every page of the form I have 100 links to click but the issue is that I don't know how to tell iMacro to keep clicking the links in the table without specifying each link's name in the attribute:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=TXT:Trip<SP>to<SP>China
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=TXT:Trip<SP>to<SP>Mexico
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=TXT:Trip<SP>to<SP>Japan
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=TXT:Trip<SP>to<SP>Brazil
```

See how the `ATTR=TXT` field indicates the text of the element in the table? This means to get iMacro to click all the links I have to specify every element's text....This is a pain..Is there a way I can get iMacro to click on the links without specifying the text?

**UPDATE:** Here is the updated code that highlights but won't click the first link.

```
FRAME NAME=TargetContent
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=TXT:*
'New tab opened
TAB T=2
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:win2divUW_CO_JOBDTL_VW_UW_CO_JOB_DESCR EXTRACT=TXT
TAB CLOSE


SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Documents\iMacro FILE=TestRun.csv
```

Here is what the HTML of the first link in table looks like, it is **all generated by the server**:

```
<a name="UW_CO_sd_HL$0" id="UW_CO_sd_HL$0" tabindex="72" href="javascript:hAction_win0(document.win0,'UW_CO_sd_HL$0', 0, 0, 'Trip To Tokyo', false, true);" class="PSHYPERLINK">Tokyo</a>
```

The second HTML link in table looks like:

```
<a name="UW_CO_sd_HL$1" id="UW_CO_sd_HL$0" tabindex="78" href="javascript:hAction_win0(document.win0,'UW_CO_sd_HL$1', 0, 0, 'Tonka Side', false, true);" class="PSHYPERLINK">Tonka</a>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the iMacro code after I do experimental recording and then x/y co-ordinate click. The code is from clicking the first couple of elements.

```
CLICK X=131 Y=473
TAB T=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
CLICK X=153 Y=500
TAB T=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
CLICK X=194 Y=541
TAB T=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
CLICK X=152 Y=572
TAB T=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
CLICK X=149 Y=608
TAB T=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
CLICK X=169 Y=629
TAB T=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
CLICK X=173 Y=666
TAB T=2
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can be transformed to work better.

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=TXT:Trip<SP>to<SP>*
```

For example if the links HTML looks like this

```
<a href="www.somelink.com/soomething_different_here/something.html" class="link" id="linkid">Trip to Somewhere</a>
```

Then you can use these combinations of iMacros code to click the links.

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=CLASS:link&&TXT:*

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=ID:linkid&&TXT:*

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=HREF:www.somelink.com/soomething_different_here/*&&TXT:*
```

Each of these combinations can work.

Comment: @kev the code you posted I tried but it just highlights the first link but doesn't click it.

Comment: @macroscripts: 

I updated my code but it just highlights doesn't click the link.

Comment: Try recording with experimental recording (EVENT). Uncheck the "favor elements IDs" checkbox and do some click. Click 5 links that are one after another. Then I will see how can we make it work on all.

Comment: @macroscripts I tried to make it work using the co-ordinates but the iMacro I either clicks the link too fast OR it clicks the wrong spot in the screen because it just skips over the CLICK x=* y=* line in the code. Not sure why it skips over..

Comment: @macroscripts what would work in this case? A tiresome solution I have made is to use the extract in iMacro to pull the TAG's name and a PHP file generates the code to click each element using the name I have pulled out which is still faster than manual but there has to be a faster and more dynamic way to do this

Comment: Use JavaScript scripting. It's very effective in making a script. If the imacros code works then JS should solve all issues.